# Get An Specified Match Under a String

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm trying to match the contents of a string that contains sequences of quotes using Shell Script, at the time the far I got was this:

```
et="\"He\" \"llo\""
echo $et | sed -e '/\"(.*?)\"/g'
```

Which returns this:

> "He" "llo"

But  I don't want the quote marks to appear on the result, also how can I `echo` only the first, or the second, or the third, etc. match?

Comment: DO you mean, in `"He" llo "world"`, you want `He` and `world` as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much simpler with `awk` since you can specify the double-quote to be the field separator.

```
$ et='"He" "llo"'
$ awk -F'"' '{print $2}' <<<$et
He
$ awk -F'"' '{print $4}' <<<$et
llo
```

***Note***: This is also scalable and the strings fields will be in multiples of two, i.e $2, $4, $6, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much! This was a lot easier (and understandable) than using `sed` with regular expressions. Could you explain why it works using multiples of two?

Comment: Because awk will split at each " so the parts will be ' ', 'He, ' ', and 'llo'.

Comment: Sorry the first part will be an empty string

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e 's/"\([^"]*\)"/\1/g'` will remove quotes around balanced `"` quotes. To only show the first, second match etc with sed you probably have to make different capture groups.

```
$ echo '"1" "2" "3"' | sed -e 's/"\([^"]*\)" "\([^"]*\)" "\([^"]*\)"/\2/g'
2
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided that what is wanted is only the text between the first pair of quotes, here is a solution with perl:

```
echo $et | perl -ne '/"[^"]+"/ and print "$&\n";'
```

This will also handle quotes witin quotes if they are preceded by a backslash:

```
echo $et | perl -ne '/"[^"\\]+(\\.[^"]*)*"/ and print "$&\n";'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
[srikanth@myhost ~]$ echo "\"He\" \"llo\"" | awk ' { match($0,/([A-Za-z]+)[" ]+([A-Za-z]+)/,a); print a[1]","a[2]} '
He,llo
```